# XML from HttpWebRequest directly into dataset. (VB.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, stream, dataset

I have an update server that has an XML to tell the updater function of an application the details/files required etc. At the moment, i have to grab the xml, save it, then load the saved xml into a dataset as follows:

```
 Private Function GetXML() as XMLDocument  
        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://somewebsite.com/current.xml")
        Try
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

            If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
                Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
                document.LoadXml(contents)
                Return document
              Catch ex As Exception
           End Try
End Function

Private Sub DoUpdate()

    Dim ServerXML as XMLDocument = GetServerXML()
    ServerXML.Save("Server.xml")

    Dim ServerDataSet as new DataSet
    ServerDataSet.ReadXml("Server.xml")
End Sub
```

There must be a quicker way without saving the local file, but Im obviously stuck and have resorted to the endless knowledge of the internet.

Some Simple thing like:

```
Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
ServerDataset.ReadXML(reader)
```

Go INTERNET do you thing! :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that:

```
   Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://somewebsite.com/current.xml")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
        Dim serverdataset As New DataSet
        serverdataset.ReadXml(reader)
```

Does infact; work. I had an XML formatting problem that saving it to a file then reopening it would work, but loading it via a reader would not.